# How to connect C++ dll to C# project?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll

I have a `dll` file that was made in C++ and i need to connect it to my C# `winform` app to use different methods from there. I tried to give a reference to it as I done before with ordinary C# `dll's` but there was exception about it, because of wrong format of the `dll`. 
After that i tried to use `DllImport` as i was recommended and it's works pretty good. So, my question is, is the `DllImport` is only solution at this situation ?

Comment: Is it the only solution ? no. Is it the easiest / cleanest one yes. In rare case it is required to have a referenced dll. In these case you need to create a wrapper dll in vb6 or sometime vb.net works it depend on the types used and reference that COM dll.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is **Yes**, `[DllImport]` is *the* way to import native methods.

There are others like a C++/CLI wrapper or COM, but they are more work and less fun.